# Can silk be considered as an electret?

Tags: electrostatics

In a video from MinutePhysics, I heard that the N95 masks use electrets to trap very small particles electrically.

In the case of cloth masks, silk has the property to electrostatically filter particles.

So my question is, does this make silk an electret? If not, what is the difference between the electrostatic properties of an electret and silk fibre?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, this is currently an open question as to whether or not filters made from silk are rightly considered "electrets." Generally, I think the issue is that the innate electric dipole moment required for an electret to be effective is too weak for silk, so they must be [treated](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-0563-1_6) in some way with other materials.

However, silk nanofabrics have shown great potential for filtration purposes, especially regarding pollutants such as PM$_{2.5}$. See [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12274-016-1145-3) paper for a study about this, where they found silk nanofibers to have very high filtration efficacy for particulate matter.

For a larger discussion about these things, see [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7464808/) paper. Specifically section 5.4 and the discussion at the end where they describe current methods, including ways of taking advantage of electret and nanofiber properties of materials.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and the resources. I will hit you back after referring.